# android bluetooth receive continuos incomming data from paired device

Tags: android

I have used the below code to detect the active bluetooth devices and create a list of them.
Once the active bluetooth device list is prepared we can select one device from list and send connection request to that device. Once the requested device accept connection request i need
to get continuous incomming data signal from paired device.

```
protected void connect(BluetoothDevice device) {
        try {
            Log.d(TAG,"connect bluetooth");
            // Create a Socket connection: need the server's UUID number of
            // registered
            Method m = device.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket",
                    new Class[] { int.class });
            socket = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(device, 1);
            socket.connect();
            Log.d(TAG, ">>Client connectted");
            inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
            socket.getOutputStream();
            int read = -1;
            final byte[] bytes = new byte[2048];
            while (true) {
                synchronized (obj1) {
                    read = inputStream.read(bytes);
                    Log.d(TAG, "read:" + read);
                    if (read > 0) {
                        final int count = read;
                        String str = SamplesUtils.byteToHex(bytes, count);
                        //                      Log.d(TAG, "test1:" + str);
                        String hex = hexString.toString();
                        if (hex == "") {
                            hexString.append("<--");
                        } else {
                            if (hex.lastIndexOf("<--") < hex.lastIndexOf("-->")) {
                                hexString.append("\n<--");
                            }
                        }
                        hexString.append(str);
                        hex = hexString.toString();
                        //                      Log.d(TAG, "test2:" + hex);
                        if (hex.length() > maxlength) {
                            try {
                                hex = hex.substring(hex.length() - maxlength,
                                        hex.length());
                                hex = hex.substring(hex.indexOf(" "));
                                hex = "<--" + hex;
                                hexString = new StringBuffer();
                                hexString.append(hex);
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                                Log.e(TAG, "e", e);
                            }
                        }
                        _handler.post(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, ">>", e);
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                    getResources().getString(R.string.ioexception),
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        } finally {
            if (socket != null) {
                try {
                    Log.d(TAG, ">>Client Socket Close");
                    socket.close();
                    socket = null;
                    // this.finish();
                    return;
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, ">>", e);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I need to detect continuous incomming data signals.Is it possible to do it.

Comment: hey how you are passing particular device address to this from list of available devices.? help me.

Comment: Hi use this code to get device address from list of devices:
result = new Intent(ACTION_PAIRING_REQUEST);
   result.putExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE, _devices.get(devicePosition));
   result.putExtra(EXTRA_PAIRING_VARIANT, EXTRA_PAIRING_VARIANT);
   BluetoothDevice finalDevice = result.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
where _device is the object like List<BluetoothDevice> _device=new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>()